# Where is my mistake in verifying independence of X^2 and Y^2?

Tags: self-study, distributions, joint-distribution

This is the question assigned to me:

> Let X and Y be two continuous random variables having joint pdf $\
>  f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \frac{1 + xy}{4} , −1≤x≤1,−1≤y≤1 $. Show that $X^2$
>   and $Y^2$ are independent.

This is the work I have so far:
$$ W=X^2, Z =Y^2 \implies X =\pm\sqrt{W},Y =\pm\sqrt{Z} $$
$$ 
 J = \begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial X} & \frac{\partial W}{\partial Y}\\
\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}& \frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 2X & 0 \\0 & 2Y\end{vmatrix} = \pm 4XY $$
$$ f_{W,Z}(w,z) =f_{X,Y}(\pm\sqrt{w},\pm\sqrt{z}).|J|^{-1} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{wz}}{16 \sqrt{wz}}$$
Clearly, the above can't be separated into a product of a function of w and a function of z. Where did I go wrong? Any hints for this question?

Comment: Integrate $f$ twice to obtain the distribution function (not the density!) for $(X^2,Y^2)$: evaluated at $(\xi,\eta)$ for $0\le\xi\le 1$ and $0\le\eta\le 1$ it is $\sqrt{\xi\eta}$.  The conclusion follows immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this transformation is 4-1, so we have to write $$f_{W,Z}(w,z)=|J_1|f_{X,Y}(\sqrt{w},\sqrt{z})+|J_2|f_{X,Y}(-\sqrt{w},\sqrt{z})+|J_3|f_{X,Y}(\sqrt{w},-\sqrt{z})+|J_4|f_{X,Y}(-\sqrt{w},-\sqrt{z}),$$ where it turns out the jacobians are all the same, 
$$|J_1|=|J_2|=|J_3|=|J_4|=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{wz}}.$$
We can then write out the joint as
$$f_{W,Z}(w,z)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{wz}}\left[2\frac{1+\sqrt{{wz}}}{4}+2\frac{1-\sqrt{{wz}}}{4}\right].$$
You should be able to simplify it from there and work out the joint range.